# How to hide password from processes list?

Tags: svn

If I command 'svn co xxx --username xxx --password xxx' and 'ps ax | grep svn', I will see  unprotected password. How I can avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an SSH key without a passphrase or use the [expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) command to pretend an interactive session where you do not need to put the password in the command line.